# Why does Scaffolded MVC applications have data access in the controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

This is a general question: When you scaffold a project using entity framework the controllers will use a db connection and pass things like ID's to it and return the Model to your View.

Shouldn't it be passing the ID to your Model which then handles the the query logic?

It is my understanding in mvc your data access should be done in your model so having something like the following:

```
public ActionResult Customer(int id)
{
    View(db.Customers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id = id)) //Where this view accepts a CustomerModel
}
```

Should be

```
public ActionResult Customer(int id)
{
    var model = new CustomerModel(id) //Get customer logic is done within the model
    View(model)
}
```

I see a lot of the first example when building a scaffolded project. Especially for the auto generated `Edit` functions.  Shouldn't those CRUD operations be housed within the models?  Or is this something unique to Entity Framework?

If you take EF out of the equation would handling all CRUD functions within the models be the correct way to design it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're confusing MVC, the pattern, with MVC, the Microsoft framework. Understandable, of course, given the name Microsoft chose, but in actuality, ASP.NET MVC only very loosely adheres to MVC, the pattern.

Namely, what most new developers coming to ASP.NET MVC see as the Model, is merely an *entity*. It's little more than a DTO class to hold data as it shuffles to/from the database. It should *absolutely not* contain querying logic.

Most ASP.NET MVC developers end up adding a service/repository layer and view models into the mix. Together, these three, the entity, the service/repository layer, and an assortment of view models, comprise the Model of MVC. The service/repository is responsible for handling the CRUD functions and other database-related business logic, while the view model is responsible UI-related business logic. The entity is only something EF can stuff data into.

Comment: This certainly makes things much clearer. I was not drawing a distinction between the two.  So if you wanted to adhere to industry MVC standards would you simply create your own model that implements or extends Entities? This way you could do all your crud operations while keeping the controller blind to the data access.

Comment: That's pretty much what your service/repository is. It's going to be a class, which provides a set of methods that return specific data sets or do specific operations that your applications needs. The controller *will* be dependent on this class, but the actual database logic can be kept out of the controller.

Comment: Very good, this answers a lot of the discrepancies i have seen between MVC and Microsofts version.

Answer (score 0):

imho, you are mixing (at least) two concepts:

- data model : used/exposed by the data layer
- view model : used/consumed by the view renderer

The controller makes (among other and through a business domain layer) the bond between the two.

AND NO: the view does not need (must not) to see the data layer.

Finally: this question may be opinion based (see the imho).

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of preference really. Personally I like to keep my models as dumb objects but you may prefer to use your models for CRUD also. Your example of getting a customer by passing an ID into the constructor is not the best idea as you'll then have a hard dependency in your model to the DbContext which will make testing difficult and lead to problems.

The scaffolded controllers interact directly with the DbContext to do only the minimum amount necessary and keep things simple. If you require additional logic, you would refactor this out somewhere else.

As a side note, it's possible to customise the scaffolding in Visual Studio - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/04/03/creating-a-custom-scaffolder-for-visual-studio.aspx